# Joomla incorrectly displays the modules of the homepage on blog articles page

Tags: joomla-3.6, seo, module-display

The Blog article URL is like the following: http://example.com/en/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=166&Itemid=140. It only shows the modules that are assigned specifically to the homepage along with the article.

However, if I disable the `Search Engine Friendly URLs` in the admin settings, it works fine. It only happens to the blog article page, the blog overview page displays fine with proper modules. The Joomla version I am using is 3.6.5.

It only started happening recently, no module or Joomla update happened recently. Only new articles have been inserted, I tried disabling those articles too, no luck. Can someone guide on resolving this issue?

Comment: Are you using Advanced Module Manager or sh404 (or similar)?

Comment: Nope, just the standard Joomla's SEO Friendly Url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that specific version of Joomla had trouble getting the `lang` param. Changing the URL to http://example.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=166&Itemid=140&lang=en resolved it. Not sure how or why, but it works now.